# How to compute this calculation efficiently in java?

Tags: java

I want to implement the following calculation taking a positive int lower than 32 to get another int:
0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 4, 4 => 8, 5 => 16, 6 => 32, 7 => 64, 8 => 128, ..., 31 => ‭1073741824‬

I can use an array of ints of 32 positions. I can also use an expression with a test to 0, to return 0, and a left shift of one n-1 times (sorry, impossible to attach code, editor rejects).

Right now, I am using a static table of ints, and I am happy with it. But, **I wonder if there is a way to compute the result with a simple calculation that may perform as fast as an access to a table ?**

UPDATE. Here are the 4 solutions (f1, f2, f3, f4) I have tested so far. I had already implemented f1 and f2 before asking. I tested f3 and f4 after receiving answers:

```
    private static final int[] table =
            new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536,
                1<<17, 1<<18, 1<<19, 1<<20, 1<<21, 1<<22, 1<<23, 1<<24, 1<<25, 1<<26, 1<<27, 1<<28, 1<<29, 1<<30 };

    private static final int f1( int v ) { return table[v]; }

    private static final int f2( int v ) { return v == 0 ? 0 : 1<<(v-1); }

    private static final int f3( int v ) { return v == 0 ? 0 : (int)Math.pow( 2, v-1 ); }

    private static final int f4( int v )
    {
        switch ( v )
        {
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1: return 1;
        case 2: return 2;
        case 3: return 4;
        case 4: return 8;
        case 5: return 16;
        case 6: return 32;
        case 7: return 64;
        case 8: return 128;
        case 9: return 256; 
        case 10: return 512;
        case 11: return 1024;
        case 12: return 2048;
        case 13: return 4096;
        case 14: return 8192;
        case 15: return 16384;
        case 16: return 32768;
        case 17: return 65536;
        case 18: return 131072;
        case 19: return 262144;
        case 20: return 524288;
        case 21: return 1048576;
        case 22: return 2097152;
        case 23: return 4194304;
        case 24: return 8388608;
        case 25: return 16777216;
        case 26: return 33554432;
        case 27: return 67108864;
        case 28: return 134217728;
        case 29: return 268435456;
        case 30: return 536870912;
        case 31: return 1073741824;
        default: return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of *table* are you talking about? Is it a `Map` or a `List`?

Comment: @deHaar Array is mentioned earlier in the question.

Comment: Sounds like you can use 2 raised to (the number-1)

Comment: Your best bet would be to try implementing different methods yourself and doing some benchmarking. I doubt someone benchmarked something like this. And I don't think you will see much difference for such a simple task.

Comment: I think that storing a 1d array `new int[]{0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., ‭1073741824‬}` may be cheaper

Comment: I implemented the two ways I mention in my question and benchmarked them. But I wonder if there may be a third one I did not think of ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
int answer = 0;
if(input == 0)
{
    answer = 0;
}
else
    answer = (int)Math.pow(2, input-1);
```

If the input is `0`, your output will be 0.

If your input is 4, your output will be `2^(4-1)` = `2^3` = 8

Comment: The question was what the most efficient solution would be. Simple lookup array seems to have better performance (which probably doesn't matter that much).

Comment: @Amongalen The question also asks for a simple calculation to perform the task. I assumed this possibility had slipped OP's mind, so I provided a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (input == 0) {
    return 0;
} else
    return 1 << input - 1;
}
```

Using bitshifts is fast, and it doesn't run the risk of a cache miss that memory access has.

Comment: That is exactly the second solution I have mentioned in my question. But, the test to 0 makes it slower than access to a table.

Comment: How do you know that it is slower than access to a table? Have you done any benchmarks? If not, what is your question based on?

Comment: Yes, I have a benchmark, but, that is not the point. I am curious if someone can think of a solution other than the two I have presented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the limit on input parameter you can even use `switch` (not recommended for maintainability purposes).

```
switch (n) {
    case 0:
        return 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        return 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        return 2;
        break;
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    case 31:
        return ‭1073741824‬;
        break;
    default:
        return -1;
}
```

This is memory optimized, since we are not storing any values in array.